# STM32 SYSCLK and CORTEX SYSTEM TIMER

Tags: stm32, arm, stm32f4, cortex-m4, cortex

What is the difference between the two?
[image]

Comment: The first rectangle has got a gray border.  The second rectangle has got a blue border.  Is that not the difference you're interested in?  No?  Then you might as well tell us why you are asking, and what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.  In the meantime, -1.

Comment: I am trying to use SysTick as a delay, so I got confusion about which of these two will have end effect to my timing delay. Because there is a option to change both to different value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, `SYSCLK` is the clock the other clocks in the processor are derived from, including but not limited to core clock and peripheral clocks, the other is the clock which clocks the systick timer peripheral.

Comment: Lots of clocks.